# Custom PHP script throws critical error ONLY when editing page

Tags: php, scripts

I have the following script added to *functions.php* in my **child** theme:

```
function getlatestfile() { 
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('wp-content/uploads/cams/'));
    foreach ($iterator as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()) continue;
        $path = $file->getPathname();
    }
    return "<img src='https://mysite.url/" . $path . "' />";
}
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('getfieldimage', 'getlatestfile');
```

I can save the code, insert the shortcode `[getfieldimage]` on the page, and the page **indeed displays** the latest image. No complains.
But when trying to edit again the page containing the shortcode, WP tells me that there's a critical error, and wants me to go to https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/ . Cannot get any helpful info there.

Comment: What's the critical error? Check your PHP error log to find out the actual error message. Also, if no files are found `$path` will be undefined, it has no initial/default value, and there is no escaping around it. You're also using a relative path not an absolute path so the location it's looking in will change depending on which PHP file gets loaded, it's even possible it's trying to search `wp-admin/wp-content/.....`. That troubleshooting page is aimed at end users not developers, you should go to the developer hub at developer.wordpress.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ABSPATH helps to display the page in the backend in editmode. But for the frontend, the path for the `<img../>` tag needs to be modified. `cutprefix()` function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517067/remove-a-string-from-the-beginning-of-a-string)) does the job.

This is the working solution for the front- and backend:

```
function getlatestfile() {

  $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/cams' ));
  foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()) continue;
    $path = $file->getPathname();
  }
  $path = cutprefix($path, '/home/username/web/mysite.url/public_html/');
  return("<img src='https://mysite.url/" . $path . "' />");
}


function cutprefix($str, $prefix){
  if (substr($str, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
    $str = substr($str, strlen($prefix));
  } 
  return $str;
}
```

Thanks to [Pat J](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/16121/pat-j) for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

When you're editing the page, you're in the directory `wp-admin`, and `wp-admin` doesn't contain `wp-content` (they're both children of your site's root directory).

Instead of `'wp-content/uploads/cams/'`, I'd recommend `ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/cams/'` which should work wherever you might be in the WordPress environment.

Comment: ABSPATH gives me the following when examining the page in the browser: ```/home/_hostinguser_/web/example.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/cams/image1.jpg```. This is the from the root of my hosting account. 

In the front, I see an empty frame with the broken image icon. But yes, in the backend, I can access the page now.